# Find with '-type d' not working if the path contains symlinks?

Tags: find, freebsd, symlink

I have a directory structure something like this (I've simplified it for this question):

```
/dirX
/dirX/d/d1     [and contained files+subdirs]
/dirX/d/d1/d2  [and contained files+subdirs]
/dirX/d/d1/d3  [and contained files+subdirs]
/dirX/d/d4     [and contained files+subdirs]
/dirX/d/d4/d5  [and contained files+subdirs]
/dirX/d/d4/d6  [and contained files+subdirs]
/dirX/d/d7     [and contained files+subdirs]

/dirY
/dirY/idx
/dirY/idx/d2 -> symlink to /dirX/d/d1/d2
/dirY/idx/d5 -> symlink to /dirX/d/d4/d5
/dirY/idx/d7 -> symlink to /dirX/d/d7
```

I want to execute a command on all directories within the dirY/idx hierarchy. The usual basic command would be `find /dirY/idx -type d -exec CMD {} \;`

To my surprise, it fails after depth = 1. I'm fairly sure it must be because `find` is stopping at the symlinks - but how do I prevent that behaviour and follow all links?

If I remove the `-type d` primary, it descends into the symlinked dirs correctly, but then doesn't limit itself to directories in the search. If I limit the found files to directories, it stops at the symlink level. Ordinarily it will search the entire hierarchy for files matching the primaries, but in this case it isn't.

I've tried the symlink behaviour options -H -L -P (even though -P is a default value) - I'm on FreeBSD - but without luck.

I can't use nested find, or find link OR dir, because the issue could come up arbitrarily at other places in the tree as well. I'm fairly sure the symlink handling args are there in order to solve this kind of thing, maybe I'm misunderstanding what they do.

How do I fix my find command?

Comment: `find -L dirY/idx -type d` returns the directories in the symlinked tree.

Comment: How did you test the option `-H`, `-L` and -P? Could you give the full commands?

Comment: Do you have an alias for find?